# R Loop error using character

Tags: r, for-loop, character

I have the below function which inserts a row into a table (new_scores) based upon the attribute that I feed into it (where the attribute represents a table that I select things from):

```
    buildNewScore <- function(x) {

  something <- bind_rows(new_scores,x%>%select(ATT,ADJLOGSCORE))

  return(something)

}
```

Which works fine when I define x.

But when I try to create a for loop that feeds the rest of my attributes into the function it falls over as I'm feeding in a character.

```
attlist <- c('Z','Y','X','W','V','U','T','RT','RO')    


record_count <- length(attlist)      

for (x in c(1:record_count)){

  buildNewScore(attlist[x])

}
```

I've tried to convert the attribute into other classes but I can't get the loop to use anything I change it to (name, data.frame etc.).

Anyone have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong - is my attlist vector in the wrong format?

Thanks,
Spikelete.

Comment: Usually, you apply pipe operators to objects you are applying your pipe to 'Z' (if I understand correctly what is being passed in the function).

Comment: Thanks Konrad.  Sorry I'm new to R, could you put that in an example as I'm not following it at the min.  Thanks, Spikelete

Comment: Your function would look like that: `bind_rows(new_scores,'Z'%>%select(ATT,ADJLOGSCORE))`. Also what are those objects `ATT` and the other one?

Comment: Ah right - I tried to remove the quotes on the 'Z' by using buildNewScore(as.name(attlist[x])) but the function doesn't like it being classed as a name. ATT is a column in table Z and has in it's rows Z1, Z2, Z3 etc.  ADJLOGSCORE is also a column in table Z and contains integers.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a fully reproducible example with a sample data. Broadly speaking, inserting rows to a data frame in R is easy but I would find it easier to reflect on the actual problem if all the data frames were available. If letters are data frames why create character vector with them? Wouldn't be easier to have them in a list and jump through the list elements applying any function you want? It looks like a very convoluted way of doing a simple thing.